# Cannot install a branch from someone else's repository using pip

Tags: git, pip, installation

I need to install `pycocotools` under Linux. [Here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/6) it says that I can do that with

```
pip install git+https://github.com/waleedka/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI
```

However, when I execute the above command (from a virtual environment `my_env`), I get this answer:

```
(my_venv) ...:~/Mask_RCNN$ pip install git+https://github.com/waleedka/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI
[1] 22087
(my_venv) ....:~/Mask_RCNN$ Collecting pycocotools from git+https://github.com/waleedka/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools
  Cloning https://github.com/waleedka/cocoapi.git to /tmp/pip-build-qo_7ubcm/pycocotools
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

At this point, since `git` is prompting me for a username, I use my GitHub username, but from the answer I guess it was looking for the username (and password?) of the repository owner:

```
 MyUserName
MyUserName: command not found

[1]+  Stopped                 pip install git+https://github.com/waleedka/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools

[1]+  Stopped                 pip install git+https://github.com/waleedka/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools
```

The installation failed. Also, apparently now I have a hanging background job:

```
ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
20079 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
22087 pts/0    00:00:00 pip
22094 pts/0    00:00:00 git
22095 pts/0    00:00:00 git-remote-http
22390 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

How can I install the correct branch of `pycocotools`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is that you need to use quotes `'` to handle the ampersand `&` operator that is in this part of the command: `&subdirectory=PythonAPI`.

Also it seems that repository https://github.com/waleedka/cocoapi/ was moved to https://github.com/waleedka/coco/

So, I tried this command, and it doesn't require authentication from me, but failed because I don't have Cython installed:

```
sanyash@sanyash-ub16:~$ pip3 install 'git+https://github.com/waleedka/coco.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI'

Collecting pycocotools from git+https://github.com/waleedka/coco.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI
  Cloning https://github.com/waleedka/coco.git to ./pip-build-2pxyynzt/pycocotools
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-2pxyynzt/pycocotools/PythonAPI/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
    ImportError: No module named 'Cython'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2pxyynzt/pycocotools/PythonAPI
```

Despite I can't show you the full succsessful installation of `pycocotools`, hope my answer will help you.